# Transition to grandfather state in ui-routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there a way to go to grandfather state? Without using the literal name of it.

```
$state.go('^'); // will go to a parent state.
$state.go('^.sibling'); // will go to a sibling state.
$state.go('.child.grandchild'); // will go to a grandchild state.
```

I need something like:

```
$state.go('^.parent');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple: `$state.go('^.^');`

They use it on their documentation site in a picture, but not explicitly.

Also, it seems to work on multiple levels as well: `$state.go('^.^.^');`

Comment: I guess i should have tried that. Thanks! It worked perfectly.